# How to select jQ-ui autocomplete widget's unique remaining choice by using Tab or Enter alone?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page that uses several [jQuery UI autocomplete widgets](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/momc4o6e/) shows *a very simplified* version of how I'm using these widgets.  (In particular, the widget's `select` handler implements the following behavior: once the selection is made, its value is displayed next to the `Selected:` label, and the `input` field is blanked out.)

---

In the jsFiddle, the set of possible choices for the widget are such that, if one types the letter `b` in the blank, a drop-down list appears, showing all the available choices that begin with `b`:

[image]

At this point, the user can finalize the choice in at least two ways:

1. clicking on one of the displayed choices using the mouse;
2. using the down-arrow key to highlight the desired choice, and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>;

---

**I would like to add one more way to finalize the choice**, namely:

3. continuing to type *until the desired choice is the only remaining one* in the drop-down list, and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>;

Both methods 2 and 3 end with the pressing of <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but whereas method 2 uses the down-arrow key to highlight the desired choice, method 3 establishes the desired choice by eliminating all the other choices.

For example, if method 3 were available, the following sequence of interactions should have as its net result the selection of the value `b100`:

1. click on the jsFiddle's interface's `Run` button (near the top left of the page);
2. click in lower-left panel's input field (an insertion point should appear in the input field, and the field itself may become highlighted with a blue outline;)
3. type the string `b1` (at this point, the drop-down menu should show only one remaining choice, namely, `b100`);
4. type either <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>;

---

This next [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83n5m0mv/) shows my first steps in this direction.  My strategy is based on a handler of the keydown event:

```
function keydown(e){
    var code = e.keyCode;
    if (code == 9 || code == 13) {
        var n = $('#menu').autocomplete('widget').find('li').length;
        console.log(n + ' choice(s) remaining');
        if (n==1) {
            // ???
        }
    }
}

$('input').keydown(keydown);
```

This code correctly detects when the `input` element receives a <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and determines how many choices remain.  What I'd now like to know is what to replace the line `// ???` with in order to invoke the widget's `select` method *as if* the user had actually clicked on the down-arrow before having pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>

IOW: **How do I simulate the triggering of the `select` handler programmatically?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there will be only one unique choice, you can directly trigger 'click' event on that.

```
function keydown(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode;
    if (code == 9 || code == 13) {
        var results = $(this).autocomplete('widget').find('li.ui-menu-item');
        if (results.length == 1) {
            results.trigger('click');
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/83n5m0mv/2/

Comment: Thanks.  I think the `.eq(0)` may be omitted: `results.trigger('click')`.

Comment: Yes, because we are checking that the length of the results array is 1, we can avoid eq(0). Edited the post. Thanks.